# Golang app on Heroku htaccess basic auth

Tags: .htaccess, heroku, go

Is possible use htaccess on golang application running in heroku??
I had read this [link](https://gist.github.com/bbrewer97202/3316425#gistcomment-1833299) but the solution doesn't work for me (also, the command htpasswd is not recognized in the heroku bash, but I made the htpasswd file usin [this tool](http://www.htaccesstools.com/)).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Go web application is a server so no need to use Apache httpd server, especially on Heroku that has crystal clear deployment instructions for Go :

https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/go

Follow these instruction closely and you'll find out there is no need for Apache.

htaccess and htpasswd are related to Apache httpd server, they are Apache configuration files.

Finally, Go standard library gives you all the tools you need to implement basic auth yourself :

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.BasicAuth

Comment: Thanks @mpm. I know that apps with golang doesn`t use Apache or another web server, om fact my app is running since two months in heroku using Revel. Ok!! I Will check this library and search for a Revel auth library too. Thank you.

Comment: OK!! done... finally I made an http authentication using as example this: https://github.com/revel/samples/tree/master/booking Thanks anyway @mpm